# Blank version-line for topics without version in review

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design, documentation-review

Some proposed changes seem to show a blank `version-line` for topics without versions specified.

**Examples of `version-line` with version:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/125347
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/125441

> [image: Image 1]

**Examples of `version-line` without version:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/127128

> [image: Image 2]
>
> ---
>
> `version-line` changed to #000000:
>
> [image: Image 3]

```
<span class="version-line"></span>
```

It seems like this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.